# Python Selenium - NoSuchElementException although the value was found

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception

I'm running a python selenium script in a lambda function on AWS.

With xpath I try to find the pagination button to move to the next page.

I use the following code:

```
button_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-at="pagination-next"]')
```

The code works, because I'm able to print it and event extract the URL and also print it:

```
url = button_next.get_attribute("href")
```

But in the log I get the following error but after I was able to print it:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@data-at="pagination-next"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 4.14.255-276-224.499.amzn2.x86_64 x86_64)
: NoSuchElementException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 69, in lambda_handler
    button_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-at="pagination-next"]')
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 368, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 858, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@data-at="pagination-next"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 4.14.255-276-224.499.amzn2.x86_64 x86_64)
```

What is the issue here? Why do I get this error, although the xpath just worked before.

Answer (score 2):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-at='pagination-next']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-at='pagination-next']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Additionally, ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.2.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v102.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=102.0.5005.61/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=102.0* (as per [chromedriver=102.0.5005.61 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/102.0.5005.61/notes.txt)).

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast and detailed reply!
I'm not sure if it helps in my case, because I don't click the URL, instead I use it in a while-loop with: "driver.get(url)"

Can you advise what to do in my case?

I know I need to updated Selenium e.g., but it is a real hassle to do so in AWS lambda. (I'm a newbie to the AWS world :-) )

Comment: It might be due to the last page when it no longer exists or is disabled. You have to check if exists using try except.

Comment: @Max In that case you may like to raise a new question with all the relevant details and your code trials.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I exported screenshot to find out what is going on and run into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669535/python-selenium-scraper-pagination-to-next-page-shows-error-scrap-protection-f
ArundeepChohan no it is not the last page. Thanks for the hint.